# OS X + Java + Splash image + fileDialog : no files in dialog file open

Tags: java, macos, swing, user-interface, dialog

When I create and run a runnable Java application (JAR) with Splash screen, when activating the File Open dialog, no files are loaded in the dialog. The search wheel keeps turning and nothing happens. However when I omit the Splash images (from the Manifest.mf) file, the File Open dialog runs fine.
Also on Windows I have no problem. Only on OS X I have this problem. Tested it on both 10.8 and 10.9.

BTW I deliberately use the older FileDialog class instead of the JFileChooser, because on OS X the fileDialog looks more native OS X.

BTW the same behaviour is there when I use the AppBundler to create a OS X App and specify the Splash screen as:

I have created a very simple test program to illustrate.

What am I missing?
Who can help?
Is this a bug?

1) The sample Java code.

```
package fileDialog_Sample;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory;

public class TestSwing extends JFrame {

    Frame frame = null;

    public TestSwing() {

        initUI();
        frame = this;
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("exit.png");

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

        JMenuItem oMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open", icon);
        oMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        oMenuItem.setToolTipText("Open file");
        oMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("In File - Open");
            openFileMenu();
            }
        });
        file.add(oMenuItem);

        JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit", icon);
        eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");
        eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        file.add(eMenuItem);

        menubar.add(file);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        String lcOSName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        Boolean IS_MAC = lcOSName.startsWith("mac os x");
        Boolean IS_WINDOWS = lcOSName.startsWith("windows");

        if (IS_MAC) {

            // take the menu bar off the jframe
            System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");

            // set the name of the application menu item
            //  System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", translations.getString("application.title"));
            System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "LightroomStatistics Viewer");
        }


        setTitle("Simple menu");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static void openFileMenu() {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
          FileDialog fc;
        fc = new FileDialog(frame, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fc.setDirectory(System.getProperty("user.home"));

        fc.setVisible(true);
        String fn = fc.getFile();
        if (fn == null)
          System.out.println("You cancelled the choice");
        else
          System.out.println("You chose " + fn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestSwing ex = new TestSwing();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2) build.xml file without the splash screen setting for the Manifest.mf file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project FileDialog_Sample with Jar-in-Jar Loader">
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="D:/Temp/LRS_Viewer/FileDialog.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="fileDialog_Sample.TestSwing"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="D:/Eclipse/FileDialog_Sample/bin"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

3) build_Splash.xml, same build file, yet now with the splash screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project FileDialog_Sample with Jar-in-Jar Loader">
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="D:/Temp/LRS_Viewer/FileDialog_Splash.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="fileDialog_Sample.TestSwing"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./"/>
                <attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="splash.png"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="D:/Eclipse/FileDialog_Sample/bin"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Finally, the splash.png image is in the resources directory in the Java project.
I build it with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a bug

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8009203

Bizarrely, they've deferred the fix to JDK9 because

> It is unlikely that the client would notice the problem as it's quite
>   unusual to open the FileChooser immediately after the application
>   loads.

However you hit this bug w/o opening the FileDialog immediately after load. You can wait long after the splash is down before creating a FileDialog, and it will still be broken.

Would very much like a work-around to this, as there's no working redistributable jvm on OSX that can have a splash and a FileDialog in the same app.